# zombie browser won't open a window after calling open function

Tags: javascript, node.js, zombie.js, io.js

**tools**

**attempt 1**

- Darwin 14.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.3.0
- io.js v1.8.1
- zombie Version 4.0.7 2015-04-10

**attempt 2**

- Linux ubuntuG5 3.13.0-48-powerpc64-smp
- node.js v0.10.38
- zombie Version 3.1.0 2015-03-15

commands:

```
const Browser = require('zombie');
var url = 'https://google.com'
var browser = new Browser();
browser.open(url=url)
browser.open('http://google.com', function(err) { browser.assert.success();
});
browser.assert.text('title', 'Google');
```

Results on both machines minus filepath differences:

```
    assert.js:93
  throw new assert.AssertionError({
        ^
AssertionError: No open window with an HTML document
    at Browser.queryAll (/home/dmmmd/Dropbox/node_js_projects/node_modules/zombie/lib/index.js:432:5)
    at Assert.text (/home/dmmmd/Dropbox/node_js_projects/node_modules/zombie/lib/assert.js:307:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dmmmd/Dropbox/node_js_projects/affinity-zombie/sample_zombie.js:7:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:935:3
```

What am I missing after reading the docs at [zombie browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zombie)? Thanks in advance.

I tried some other urls, too, even localhost ones without any success.

JavaScript, node.js, io.js, and zombie are all new to me so I am basically just following recipes from the documentation and stackoverflow questions. I would appreciate any suggestions. I suspect I am missing something very simple.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Zombie, but what's going on here: `browser.open(url=url)`? Shouldn't that just be `browser.open(url)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been unanswered for a while but I've been working around a similar error message recently.

TL;DR - User browser.visit instead of browser.open() and pass in a callback function to ensure browser's state is populated correctly.

You can do this in a number of ways:

1. Use the static method Browser.visit()

```js
const Browser = require('zombie');
var url = 'https://stackoverflow.com'
Browser.visit(url, function(error, browser) {
    browser.assert.text('title', 'Stack Overflow');
});
```

2. Use the instance method browser.visit()

```js
const Browser = require('zombie');
var url = 'https://stackoverflow.com'
var browser = new Browser();
browser.visit(url, function() {
    browser.assert.text('title', 'Stack Overflow');
});
```

3. Use the promise returned by browser.visit()

```js
const Browser = require('zombie');
var url = 'https://stackoverflow.com'
var browser = new Browser();
browser.visit(url).then(function() {
    browser.assert.text('title', 'Stack Overflow');
});
```

4. If you want to reuse the browser object after the visit, pass a no-op callback to browser.visit() to ensure the browser's state is populated.

```js
const Browser = require('zombie');
var url = 'https://stackoverflow.com'
var browser = new Browser();
browser.visit(url, function(){}); // NB: no-op callback!
browser.assert.text('title', 'Stack Overflow');
```

The browser.open() method opens a new browser tab and takes a JavaScript Object containing an url property, so your original code had a syntax error, the line

```js
browser.open(url=url)
```

should read

```
browser.open({url: url})
```

but it's not clear whether the open method actually makes the new tab visit the url - at least not from a cursory read over the source. Use browser.visit() to be on the safe side.

Comment: It seems other things can cause this error. In my case I was missing a callback on a `clickLink()` and somehow it caused that same error.

Comment: @lipsumar do you have working example with clickLink()?

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was while using `browser.fill` and `browser.pressButton`, what I did was calling `done()` before `browser.assert(...)`